# Comparing float numbers in Python gives wrong result

Tags: python

I have a Python script which saves measurement values in a `csv` file. I then read the `csv` into another python script which checks whether the results sum up to `1.0`. I noticed that my comparison script often returns false, even though if I do `print(my_sum)`, the printed result is `1.0`. Similarly, summing up the values using excel gives exactly `1.0`.

Here are my example values:

```
x = 0.926119895097366
y = 0.0248330035844995
z = 0.0490471013181347
```

The check `if (x+y+z) == 1.0` failed. However, when I do `print(x+y+z)`, the value printed is `1.0`. Similarly, using excel to sum those values gives `1.0`. However, when I run the summation in Ipython, the result is `1.0000000000000002`. What is causing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken might be helpful

Comment: floating point arithmetic is fun like that, never compare with a specific value, use for example [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, for typical use cases such as the results of arithmetic operations,  compare floats for [equality due to rounding errors](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Instead check that the two numbers are very close. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425) for alternatives.